# Datasheet doesn't include pinout info?

Tags: arduino, usb, datasheet, driver, interface

I am trying to connect arduino and usb lancard

In the datasheet, there is USB transceiver interface, containing symbol, type, pin number, description (usb D+ or D- signal).

However, the datasheet (about 20 pages) includes no information about what pin (out of 4) and what value to send to make anything work.

What reference should I refer to?

Thanks!

(I am a hardware beginner, sorry for dumb question)

Comment: its clear that English isn't your first language but your going to have to do some work to make this question answerable.

Comment: oh thank you for your advice. could you be more specify? such as 3rd sentence's grammar is broken or something like that. thanks!

Comment: from my experience, if the datasheet doesn't have enough info to make it work then you should look for a different part.

Comment: Are you talking about the datasheet for your lancard, or for the arduino? If it's the lancard, do you have a part number for it?

Comment: As I said in one of my previous comments, you'll need a card that can work with Arduino out of the box. If such cards aren't available in your area, you could try making one. You'll need a chip that's stand-alone or uses one of the popular microcontroller protocols such SPI or \$I^{2}C\$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're going the wrong direction with the hardware you have available.  If you're using a USB network adapter, it's probably one of those where you have to install drivers in the OS to make it work.  And if you have to do this, then you've got your work cut out for you trying to interface an Arduino with such a USB device.  It's not going to be as simple as an HID device (i.e. keyboard or mouse).

If you have an Arduino, why not stick with one of the tried-and-true solutions, like an Ethernet Shield?  Or try the SPI device that Jeremy Kerr has mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

As Kellenjb has said in a comment:

> if the datasheet doesn't have enough info to make it work then you should look for a different part

I think that this is excellent advice, especially if you're a beginner. Much better to spend time and effort designing, rather than wondering what the (poorly documented) hardware requires from you.

If it's an ethernet device you're looking for, then the enc58j60 is a SPI 10baseT device, well documented, and has AVR libraries already available.